# java.awt.Toolkit.createImage replacement in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to convert my Java Applet which connects to a video surveillance server to run on Android. I am having issues with trying to convert a byte array containing a JPEG image to a Bitmap object on Android.

The Applet code is:

```
private Toolkit Tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
private Image m_Image = null;

byte[] buf = this.SockClient.ReadStream(size));
m_Image = tk.createImage(buf);
```

My Android code is:

```
private Bitmap m_Image = null;
ByteBuffer bb = null;

m_Image = Bitmap.createBitmap(320,240,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

byte[] buf = this.SockClient.ReadStream(size);
bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf);
m_Image.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bb);
```

I am getting a NullPointerException after calling copyPixelsFromBuffer.

I'm guessing I am using the wrong methods to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) and `decodeByteArray()` to convert a `byte[]` of JPEG data to a `Bitmap`.